# How to read the last line in a textbox?

Tags: c#, string, linq, textbox, readlines

I have a multiline textbox that constantly gets updated.
I need to read only the last word/sentence in the textbox.

```
string lastLine = textBox1.ReadLine.Last();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (textBox1.Lines.Any())
{
    string lastLine = textBox1.Lines[textBox1.Lines.Length - 1];
}
```

And for last word:

```
string lastword = lastLine.Split(' ').Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

A textbox with the `MultiLine` property set to true has an array of `Lines` from which it is easy to extract the info required

```
int maxLines = textBox1.Lines.Length;
if(maxLines > 0)
{
    string lastLine = textBox1.Lines[maxLines-1];
    string lastWord = lastLine.Split(' ').Last();
}
```

A bit of caution here is needed. If your textBox still doesn't contain any lines you need to introduce a check on the number of lines present

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the last line from any string as follows:

```
string str = ....;

string[] lines = str.Split('\n', '\r');
string last_line = lines[lines.Length - 1];
```

To get the last line of a TextBox you can use:

```
string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split('\n', '\r');
string last_line = lines[lines.Length - 1];
```